# Comparing PropertyInfo.GetValue result when the PropertyInfo.GetType is not string

Tags: c#, object, reflection, properties, comparison

I´m comparing some properties values from two instances of the same class.

```
var vinst = prop.GetValue(workinginstance, null);
var vref = prop.GetValue(reference, null );
if ( vinst != vref) {
            info = info + String.Format( "{0} differ", prop.Name );
            valid = false;
}
```

My test class have two string props and one int.
When I compare the string values, because the string´s immutability, the results are fine: is the strings differ, the equality fails,if they are the same, equality test is true.
But when the code compare the two int properties, the result is always false. It seems to me that I need some form of casting to the PropertyInfo.GetType(), but don´t know how to do it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It may help if we could see from the declaration of each instance through to the currently included code.  From what we can see, the two integer values could actually be different, causing the check to fail.  Also, try putting a break point on the line "if ( vinst != vref) {" and check the values and types of vinst and vref

Comment: you need to cast `.ToString()` on `vinst` and `vref`, in order to compare strings not objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would change your comparison part so its not using != but rather the equals function because the getvalue returns an object and not a specific value

```
if (!vinst.equals(vref))
```